# Using separate vertex buffer and texture coord buffer and multiple indices to draw tris DirectX11

Tags: directx-11, vertex-buffer, index-buffer

So I saw these posts [DX10+ multiple vertex buffers, single index buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881584/dx10-multiple-vertex-buffers-single-index-buffer) and [Using Multiple Vertex Buffers In DX10/DX11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174028/using-multiple-vertex-buffers-in-dx10-dx11) and vague understood [Why Directx11 doesn't support multiple index buffers in IASetIndexBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649517/why-directx11-doesnt-support-multiple-index-buffers-in-iasetindexbuffer)

When rendering indexed tris, I was wondering if it is possible to have a vertex buffer and a separate texture coordinate buffer. But then specify the triangles when drawn by like a set of indices into the vertex buffer and a set of indices into the texture coordinate buffer (separate), so a total of 6 indices per triangle. So that I can reuse texture coords and vertices. Because otherwise i have to duplicate vertices for every texture coordinate which I am not too keen on.

Is this possible in DirectX 11?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicating vertices is in fact the standard solution if you need different vertex elements with shared positions.